# How to add permission in app via app inventor

Tags: android

I want to upload my app on Samsung store for this I have to add permission in the app. How i can do it in app inventor anyone can tell I am not using eclipse. I want to it only in app inventor

Answer (score 0):

The permission is added automatically by app inventor. You just need to download .apk file of your app from app inventor. Then, upload it on Samsung store.